# Calling a function that is in the same class - Django

Tags: python, django, python-3.x, python-2.7

Calling a function that is in the same class - Django

I'm confused.

I can not make this work on my project.

However, it works in a separate python-only file.

view.py

```
from .lib.rest import Rest

    class AssinaturaUpdate():
        ...
        def post(self, request, id):
            assinatura = Assinatura.objects.filter(id=id).first()
            form = FormAssinatura(request.POST)
            if form.is_valid():
                Rest.update.(self, data=form.cleaned_data, assinatura_id=assinatura.id)
            return redirect('assinatura_edit', id=id)
```

rest.py

```
class Rest():  

    def trocaPlano(self, assinatura_id):
        payload = {
            "id": assinatura_id
        }
        print(payload)

    def update(self, data, assinatura_id):

        self.trocaPlano(assinatura_id=assinatura_id)  

        headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json", "Authorization": TOKEN}
        r = requests.put(url='https://rest.com/subscriptions/'+assinatura_id, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
    ...
```

> 'AssinaturaUpdate' object has no attribute 'trocaPlano'

Comment: Where is self assigned in the above call? should probably be doing `t = Test(); t.update(..)`

Comment: The call Test.update(self... works. Only the trocaPlano() does not work

Comment: What is the value of `self` in `Test.update(self,...)`?

Comment: Pycharm ID identifies what you need to have. however, without it also does not work.

Comment: Error is show 'Test' object has no attribute 'trocaPlano'

Comment: Could you please answer my question? What is the value of `self` that you pass to `Test.update`?

Comment: update() missing 1 required positional argument: 'self'

Comment: DYZ. Self has no value

Comment: That is not possible. Please include all relevant code.

Comment: @DYZ, Is done..

Answer (score 0):

When you are accessing an object method, you need to initiate a instance of the class. So when accessing methods `trocaPlano` and `update`(those have `self` as first parameter of the method, those are referencing to object iteself, kind of like `this` in JS) of `Rest` class, you need to initiate a `Rest` class object, like using `Rest()`.

You need to update your code like this:

```
# view

from .lib.rest import Rest
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404

class AssinaturaUpdate():
    ...
    def post(self, request, id):
        assinatura = get_object_or_404(Assinatura, id=id)
        form = FormAssinatura(request.POST)
        if form.is_valid():
            Rest().update(form.cleaned_data, id)
        return redirect('assinatura_edit', id=id)

 # rest

class Rest():  

    def trocaPlano(self, assinatura_id):
        payload = {
            "id": assinatura_id
        }
        print(payload)

    def update(self, data, assinatura_id):

        self.trocaPlano(assinatura_id)  

        headers = {"Content-Type": "application/json", "Accept": "application/json", "Authorization": TOKEN}  # <-- How this token comes here
        r = requests.put(url='https://rest.com/subscriptions/'+assinatura_id, data=json.dumps(payload), headers=headers)
```

Answer (score 0):

without parameter

```
def calc_total_deduction(self):
    total_deduction = self.otherDeductions + self.calc_income_tax() + self.calc_total_pension()
    return total_deduction

def calc_net_salary(self):
    net_salary = self.calc_gross_salary() - self.calc_total_deduction()
    return net_salary
```

if it takes parameter

```
def calc_total_deduction(self):
    total_deduction = self.otherDeductions + self.calc_income_tax() + self.calc_total_pension()
    return total_deduction

def calc_net_salary(self):
    net_salary = self.calc_gross_salary(self.employee) - self.calc_total_deduction()
    return net_salary
```